# When I try to sort files in a directory containing 1a, 121a &151a, 121a file comes first before 1a file

Tags: file, sorting

Friends, I have a folder containing three files named as 1a.txt, 121a & 151a.txt. When I try to sort the files, file name 121a comes before 1a.

```
import os
path = r"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\number test"
files = os.listdir(path)
print(path)
```

**Output**:
C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\number test

```
for file in files:
    print(file)
```

But, what I want is 1a.txt, 121a.txt, 151a.txt. Need your useful feedbacks.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rename to "001.txt": when format is overall the same, it will work.